# Arranging column2 based on column1 in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two column like this

```
column 1             column 2

abc ddd def              ghij
abc ghi jkl              dddd
bbc mno qrst             wxyz
```

As you can see column 2 is having few letters from column 1. I need to sort column 2 based on the occurrence of this letters. So my column will be looking like

```
column 1             column 2

abc ddd def              dddd
abc ghi jkl              ghij
bbc mno qrst             mnoq
```

How to sort this ?

Comment: Would you be opposed to using vba for this?

Comment: @pnuts Column1 is sorted alphabatically. No column2 data are unique

Comment: @MattCremeens If it possible by vba then no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of temporary helper columns, say:

in C1:  `=MID(A1,5,3)`
in D1:  `=MATCH(LEFT(B1,3),C:C)`

and both formulae copied down you might sort B:D in order ascending for ColumnD.